# split function and integers in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, split, int, map-function

Below is the following code:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

The above code works fine but the below code throws error.Can you please explain?

```
l = input()
i = int(l.split())
m = input()
j = int(m.split())
```

The type error is : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list.
I wanted to figure out how the above part of code works and not below one.

Comment: Please post the error as well.

Comment: how does map(int,input().split()) is different from int(input().split())

Comment: Where is `map()`?

Comment: sir I didn't get you. Do you mean map(int,input().split()) or something else?

Comment: even if i use int(str(input().split()) it still throws an error. So how is map(int,input().split())  different from int(input().split())

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns an array of strings, and as you've seen, `int` can't take that as an argument. `map` takes a function reference (`int` in this case) and applies it to each member of an iterable, thus converting all the strings to ints.

Comment: so the main difference is int tries to apply for the whole string, while map applies it to individual elements of the list.ok thanks got it.

Comment: sir, string in python is iterable, right? So is it valid to write map(int,"string"). How do you justify the above behavior since it is syntactically correct but doesn't produce any output!

Comment: @Mahantesh How would `map` apply `int` to these non-integer values? And it does provide an output. In Python 3 `map` is 'lazy', it will only apply the function when consumed: `action = map(int, 'string') ;  list(action) ;Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'`

Comment: sir, I am a beginner.Can you please explain the term lazy?

Comment: @Mahantesh in the example `map(int,"string")`, map tries to iterate every character of the string, and then fails because it can't convert the first character (`s`) to an int.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation